# Angular $scope variables not being sent through $http.post. Why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there some trick I'm missing? I'm building a json, even testing it inside the page to make sure the values are assigned to the right scope variables, yet when i sent the object it received null or undefined variables. Please ignore the session variable in the console log object, it's from sessionStorage. I've done $http.post in other controllers successfully, but this one has me baffled.

The controller:

```
var com = { 'texto' : $scope.texto2,
         'cliente' : Session.recallId(), 'rating' : $scope.rating,
         'stockid' : $scope.producto.stockid };

        $scope.enviar = function() {
            /* texto:   cliente:   rating:  stockid: */ 
            console.log("sending this to alta comentario:");
            console.log(com);
            $http.post('http://somelink/rest/wsAltaComentario',
                (com))
                .success(function (data){
                    console.log("success sending to alta comentario:");
                    console.log(data);
                })
                .error(function (data){
                    console.log("error sending to alta comentario:");
                    console.log(data);
                });
        };
```

I do get back console error. 
The object being passed is logged, which looks like this:

cliente

```
null
```

rating

```
undefined
```

stockid

```
"06000001"
```

texto

```
undefined
```

It doesn't make sense, since the scope variables DO get updated in the view. I actually test it. Here's the view itself for the form:

```
   <div ng-show="IsVisible">
            <div>
                <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="reviewFormModalLabel">Escribir comentario</h4>
            </div>
            <div>
                <form class="nobottommargin" ng-submit="enviar()" id="template-reviewform" name="template-reviewform" novalidate>

                    <div class="clear"></div>

                    <div class="col_full col_last">
                        <label  for="template-reviewform-rating">Rating</label>
                        <select ng-model="rating" 
                        ng-options="r.index as r.value for r in ratings">
                            <option value="">-- Seleccionar --</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="clear"></div>

                    <div class="col_full">
                        <label for="template-reviewform-comment">Comentario <small>*</small></label>
                        <textarea ng-model="texto2" class="form-control" id="template-reviewform-comment" name="template-reviewform-comment" rows="6" cols="30" required></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col_full nobottommargin">
                        <button class="button button-3d nomargin" type="submit" id="template-reviewform-submit" name="template-reviewform-submit" value="submit">ENVIAR</button>
                    </div>
                    <pre>Comment is : {{ texto2 | json }} Rating is {{ rating | json }}</pre>

                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <button type="button" ng-hide="cerrar()" class="btn btn-default">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: it's really hard to know exactly what's going wrong here. Any chance you could put together a plunker demonstrating the problem?

http://plnkr.co/

Comment: I should note that producto.stockid is preloaded into the page (passed in from the ui-route stateParam)

Comment: Check your network tab and see what's happening there..

Comment: Like others have said it is hard to determine without a plnkr.  My guess is that your var "com" is not really being set.  It's unclear from your description if you see the dump of com (with correct data) before you send it or not.

Comment: As you can see in the console, the variables in "com" are never actually updated. Though  they do show up in the page itself from the correct $scopes.

Comment: When the model values are updated, the values in your `com` object are not because they are not references. Simple solution, move the `com` assignment into the `enviar` method.

Comment: This fixed it, thank you. Is there no other way to do this? Put a watch on the variables? I would guess that's inefficient.

Comment: I see absolutely no problem in constructing the HTTP payload immediately before making the POST request